# Spark: Could not open temporary file for buffering Mongo output

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I have a standalone cluster setup with 1 master and 1 worker (separate VMs) and in my job, I'm reading some data from mongo, then after some analysis I write it back. I've tested it from eclipse and it runs fine (locally). But when I submit my job to the cluster-master, it fails when it tries to write the data back to mongo.

Below is the error that's reported on the worker node. I can see that the tmp file (/tmp/hadoop-aga/attempt_20180620130637_0012_r_000000_0/_MONGO_OUT_TEMP/_out) is in fact created on the worker, so its probably not a filesystem permissions issue, but the files are 0 bytes.

Here is the api call I'm using to write to mongo

```
rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
            "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
            keyClass,
            BSONObject.class,
            MongoOutputFormat.class,
            outputConfig
        );
```

Error from worker:

```
2018-06-20 13:06:53 INFO  connection:71 - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:28}] to 192.168.1.6:27017
2018-06-20 13:06:53 INFO  cluster:71 - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=192.168.1.6:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=716463}
2018-06-20 13:06:54 INFO  MongoRecordWriter:60 - Writing to temporary file: /tmp/hadoop-aga/attempt_20180620130637_0012_r_000000_0/_MONGO_OUT_TEMP/_out
2018-06-20 13:06:54 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open temporary file for buffering Mongo output
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(MongoOutputFormat.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:61)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally got around this, it did turn out to be a permissions issue.

I installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (x64)" and downloaded [winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils). Then execute:

> winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp